# Non-reflexive Orlicz spaces

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces

I am looking for a good reference on [Orlicz spaces](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Orlicz_space); I would appreciate any books treating this topic from the Banach-space perspective. For example, I would like to find a reference to the following fact that every Orlicz space is complemented in its bidual. (This is clear for reflexive Orlicz spaces, of course.)

Comment: Here's a plug ... Chapter 2 in http://www.amazon.com/Processes-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications-University/dp/B008A2ILVA/

Comment: $805.92?!?!?!?!

Comment: @BillJohnson ... "only" $190 from the publisher.  And half that in soft cover.

Comment: And free if you like to be a pirate.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you the books:

(1) Krasnoselskii, Rutickii, Convex functions and Orlicz spaces

(2) Rao, Ren, Theory of Orlicz spaces

(3) Chapter 4 of Volume 1 of the book Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri, Classical Banach spaces contains interesting material on Orlicz sequence spaces.

(4) Orlicz function spaces are dealt with in the second volume of Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri, but usually in a more general context.